# square bracket "[" operator extracting inaccurate subset

Tags: r

In the following code block I would expect the 5578 to be 650.  I am unclear why it is not.

```
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".dat")
download.file("https://github.com/vz-risk/VCDB/raw/master/data/verisr/vcdb.dat", tmp, quiet=TRUE)
load(tmp, verbose=TRUE)
> dim(vcdb[vcdb$plus.dbir_year == 2018, ])
[1] 5578 2393
> vcdb %>% dplyr::filter(plus.dbir_year ==2018) %>% dim()
[1]  650 2393
> table(vcdb$plus.dbir_year == 2018)

FALSE  TRUE 
 2211   650
```

This was tried across environment resets, two different users' environments, and tested nrow() vs dim().  'df' is a data.frame.  This was not tested with other dataframes or columns.

Version information:

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             darwin15.6.0
>   system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          4.0
>   year           2017
>   month          04
>   day            21
>   svn rev        72570
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
>   nickname       You Stupid Darkness

edit1: Updated with environment version information.  Code updated to be reproducible.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, you're unlikely to get help

Comment: Like hrbrmstr said, it's hard to really provide help.  However, check the resulting dataframe from your first line (df[df$column == 2018, ]) to make sure that is giving you your expected result.  Specifically, check to make sure that you are not brining back any missing values.

Comment: This is *interesting*, certainly, but in a "huh" kind-of way. I'm also curious to know if `df$column` is an `integer`, and if you use `== 2018L` does the behavior change.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  Updated to be reproducible.

Comment: @r2evans column is numeric.  Changing to `== 2018L` returned 5578 (vs the expected 650)

Comment: (1) Since it's `numeric`, changing to `==2018L` sadly does little. (2) Links to external stores of data are generally frowned upon, partly because links can die but the question will live on with nothing available, partly because I trust that click-through problems arise everywhere and am loath to "just do it" here.

Comment: @r2evans Is there a recommended way to share the rdata file or 7789x2393 dataframe without a link?

Comment: @Pawel ah, I had thought I tested for na's, but that does appear to be it. ```> dim(vcdb[vcdb$plus.dbir_year == 2018 & !is.na(vcdb$plus.dbir_year), ])
[1]  650 2393```

Comment: @Gabe - glad you figured it out. The recommended alternative to sharing gigantic files is to share **minimal** reproducible examples. In this case, with 2393 columns, the only column you needed to share was the only one you used: `plus.dbir_year`. And I bet if you tried a couple random samples of 100 rows you would have found a subset that reproduced the problem. Of course, with such a small data frame you probably would have noticed the `NA`s by looking at the data and you wouldn't have posted the question at all - which is another benefit of making small reproducible examples.

Comment: @gregor thanks.  I appreciate the recommendation.